# Firebase - onAuthStateChanged() fires both after sign in and sign up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, firebase-authentication, redux-saga

I need to be able to figure out why did the listener fire - was it an initial sign up or sign in?

I tried using part of the user payload that comes with the callback. I tried comparing
user.metadata.createdAt and user.metadata.lastLoginAt and this usually works - if I sign up, then sign out, and then sign in - it's all ok. But it is not ok when I sign up and then simply refresh the page.

Is there a way to see some metadata about when was the last time the auth status was changed or simple - to figure out if onAuthStateChanged fired because of a sign up or sign in.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onAuthStateChanged()` fires when the auth state changes, so that is indeed both for sign-ups and sign-ins.

If you want to distinguish between the two, you can:

- Either hook the explicit `then` that you get back from the `signIn...`/`createUser` method.
- Or you can compare the `creationTime` and `lastSignInTime` in the [`user.metadata`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.usermetadata). If they're the same, the user was just created.

Comment: Hello. As I have stated in my question - the metadata is no good. If I create the user and close the browser and reopen it, when I request the auth state of the user upon app loading, the metadata will not have changed because there was no sign in.

Comment: In that case, you can still use the first option in my answer. Did you give it a try yet?

Comment: It still wouldn't work, as I have several sagas watching for logins/signups, auth state changes, etc. I guess I can "race" the sign up and sign in and get it working this way. I was hoping for a more straight-forward way and I find it weird that the firestore callback would not hold a simple value of whether this is the user's initial login after a signup or just a plain login. Anyway. Thanks for your response I guess it helped me to stop looking. Thank you.